# Error inserting data in foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to insert data into SQL table, the userID is a smallint which is a foreign key. The amount is just a decimal.

For some reason i'm getting an error, am I going about it the right way ? Thanks

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
INSERT INTO donations (userID, amount) VALUES ('10', '11')
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
```

> Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INSERT INTO donations (userID, amount) VALUES ('10', '11')
>   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHEC' at line 2

My PHP to insert this in

```
        //set feedback
        $sql = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

            INSERT INTO donations (userID, amount)
            VALUES ('30', '0');

            SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;";
```

ive also tried this

```
        //set feedback
        $sql = "SELECT donations SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

            INSERT INTO donations (userID, amount)
            VALUES ('30', '0');

            SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;";
```

Comment: Put a semicolon after the `0`.

Comment: MySQL is seeing the three lines combined as a *single* statement. (The line breaks are just whitespace, and don't mean anything to MySQL.) MySQL reads until it finds the statement delimiter that ends the statement. By default, that's a semicolon character.

Comment: Thanks this was an the issue. Strange though it works in SQL put when I come to put it in my php file it doesnt work. Updated code if you wouldnt mind taking a look please

Comment: The problem is probably how you are sending the query . . . often, you need  different functions for sending one statement versus multiple statements.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks okay.  Put a semicolon at the end of each line to demarcate the statements:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

INSERT INTO donations (userID, amount)
    VALUES ('10', '11');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks this was an the issue. Strange though it works in SQL put when I come to put it in my php file it doesnt work

Comment: Updated code if you wouldnt mind taking a look please